# Boot version 21.04 from DVD extremely slow (and even impossible using Kubuntu) - but no problem when using USB stick

Tags: kubuntu

Hello Ubuntu community,

The current version 21.04 seems to boot very, very slowly from DVD (on my two different computers).
Kubuntu 21.04 does even stop booting after 10 minutes.

However this problem does not exist when I boot 21.04 (Ubuntu or Kubuntu) from an USB stick (which I prepared before using the iso file).

Is this issue known?
All former versions (before 21.04) could be booted without problems from DVD (slowly but still acceptable).

During the startup process from a DVD (live system) many error messages are shown (but I don't see them when booting from USB stick).

Best regards,
Volker

Comment: The clue is probably in the *many error messages*. Maybe a bad burn?

Comment: DVD read speed is very slow compared to USB.  Are you sure that your expectations are reasonable?  I find that using a live session from DVD is intolerably slow these days...

Comment: May be related https://askubuntu.com/q/1336515/124466