# ubuntu 21.4 desktop iso burned to dvd fails to start

Tags: live-cd

The ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso burned to a dvd fails to start live session giving a bunch of error messages like:

```
Failed to start Snap Daemon
Failed unmounting cdrom
Failed to start Holds Snappy daemon refresh
Failed to start Ubuntu live cd installer. failed at package install time...
```

And then it stops.
It is not a problem of corruption of the downloaded iso: I have checked sha256 and it is correct, and the if I burn the same iso with Rufus on an usb stick the live session starts without problems.
It is not a problem of the dvd burner or of the dvd disc, because I have successfully burned other iso images of several different distributions (Mint, Manjaro, Mx Linux) using the same burner and dvd without having issues trying them on the same pc's.

Comment: Does this only occur on 21.04? Can you try on 20.04?

Comment: A similar issue has been reported, but may not be a duplicate. https://askubuntu.com/q/1336277/124466

Comment: If you are using Windows to burn the dvd (rufus is windows only) you can try burning it from Windows Explorer (I never sucessfully rufused a dvd)

Comment: The question should show the complete output with all errors. Not a summary, not edited. Details often contain important information that can point to possible causes.

Comment: On 20.04 startup process it is very slow and I got only a Failed unmounting cdrom in the console messages, but at the end live session starts.
As for the complete output report, I wouldn't know how to get it and post here, I believe that making a movie of the console messages is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried again today with 21.04, by checking exactly the time spent in the live session startup. After around twelve minutes from the boot, the Ubuntu logo disappears and I start to see console messages. Between those, there is one stating
A start job is running for Snap Daemon (1min19s /1min 30s).
This seems to suggest that there is a limit time of 1min 30s for that job, and if reached then the Snap Daemon fails to start.
However, this time I waited a little more, and after around 30 minutes from the boot I could finally see the graphical interface of the live session.
So I assume that this problem could be marked as solved, even if such a long time, especially compared with the relatively short one required when starting from usb, it doesn't appear to me as a normal behavior.

I assume moreover that this question can be marked as a duplicate of [Boot version 21.04 from DVD extremely slow (and even impossible using Kubuntu) - but no problem when using USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/q/1336277/124466)

Comment: I have reported this issue as a bug with workaround. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1930880

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem with 22.04. This is the last time I try installing Ubuntu from a DVD. USB seems much faster and easier.

To work around this observation, I booted Ubuntu in fail safe graphics mode and installed the OS from the trial OS by clicking the desktop icon at the bottom right corner.

The install took many hours and the graphics were buggy, but it worked.